# Bootstrap Align ICON do not vertically center with Text

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

**TL& DR:** I am trying to make sure my left and right icons align with the center text which i have successfully been able to place directly in the CENTER of the screen.

As you can see below: If i put in a couple words or a small snippet block the left and right arrows do not look centered with the centered div.

Here are the thing I have tried unsuccessfully:

1) Tried to problematically do a count of the text and have it write a new style sheet each time. That just stinks and doesn't sound right? It didn't work anyway at least on ruby on rails. *Level 10 stupid idea 5 hours wasted*

2) I could require all TEXT in the WELL to be of a certain length but then that would put specific requirements coupled with the view *Level 2 Stupid idea*

3) Searched everywhere. As you can see, I was able to get the things centered on the screen, now its the small nuisances that are specific that a general tutorial or website can not teach.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2  col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <div class="pull-left centered_left">
                <h1><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-left "> </span> </h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-8  col-sm-8  col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <div class="centered well">
                <h1 class="crop"> My ICONS do not align with this text!</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2  col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 ">
            <div class="pull-right centered_right ">
                <h1> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right "> </span>  </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

mysyle.css

```
.centered {
 position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  /* bring your own prefixes */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


.centered_left {
 position: fixed;
  top: 49%;
  left: 0%;

}

.centered_right {
 position: fixed;
  top:49%;
  right: 0%;
}

h1.crop{
     word-wrap: break-word;
     -webkit-hyphens: auto;
     -moz-hyphens: auto;
     -ms-hyphens: auto;
     -o-hyphens: auto;
     hyphens: auto;
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 12pt;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing your .centered_left, and .centered_right rules to this:

```
.centered_left {
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 left: 1%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.centered_right {
 position: fixed;
 top:50%;
 right: -1%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: CSS can either make you feel like a genius or a chimp. I always feel like a chimp. This worked.

Comment: For us that are stupid, could you explain why you did what you did. Just in case we might have to make changes?

Comment: well, I looked at what rule was centering the text, which is .centered, and used the same position, top, and transform values.  the left: 1% and right: -1% was just to correct for the width of the icons.

Comment: Brian: Try looking at this through your IPAD? It doesn't look correct. Is this a bug in bootstrap

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately I don't own a tablet so I can't see what you mean.

Comment: The same issue is with an IPHONE and an android phone?